# Debugging an AccessViolation in .NET app on a WinCE device using WinDbg

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, windbg

I'm debugging a crash on a client's .NET 2.0 WinCE (6.0) application.  I've pulled the .kdmp from the device and opened in in WinDbg, but to be honest I don't know quite what I'm looking for.  I can see that it is an Access Violation taking down the app, but that's all I can tell.  Any tips on using WinDbg for .NET Compact Framework is appreciated.  I don't have experience with the tool.

Here is the output from `!analyze -v`

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                      Win CE Exception Analysis                              *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


Debugging Details:
------------------

GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\triage\guids.ini, error 2
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.dll\4D7757B97a000\ole32.dll not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.dll\4D7757B97a000\ole32.dll not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ole32.dll/4D7757B97a000/ole32.dll not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\ole32.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\ole32.dll - file not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ole32.dll/4D7757B97a000/ole32.dll not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.dll\4D7757B97a000\ole32.dll not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\ole32.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\ole32.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\ole32.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\ole32.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: ole32.dll not found in c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug
DBGHELP: ole32.dll not found in c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug
DBGENG:  ole32.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image ole32.dll, Win32 error 0n2
DBGENG:  ole32.dll - Partial symbol image load missing image info
DBGHELP: No header for ole32.dll.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug\ole32.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug\dll\ole32.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug\symbols\dll\ole32.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: .\ole32.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: .\dll\ole32.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\dll\ole32.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: ole32.dll missing debug info.  Searching for pdb anyway
DBGHELP: c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug\ole32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug\dll\ole32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\documents and settings\thomas carvin\desktop\scanner\bin\debug\symbols\dll\ole32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: ole32.pdb - file not found
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ole32.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ole32.dll
DBGHELP: ole32 - no symbols loaded
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
80428ca8 e5913010 ldr         r3,[r1,#0x10]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 80428ca8
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000010
Attempt to read from address 00000010

FAULTING_THREAD:  0cf2001a

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000010

READ_ADDRESS:  00000010 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
+0
80428ca8 e5913010 ldr         r3,[r1,#0x10]

CE_DEVLOG: <ANALYSIS>
    <CELG_NAME>OEM</CELG_NAME>
    <CELG_VALUE>MOTOROLA MC3100R</CELG_VALUE>
</ANALYSIS>

CE_DEVLOG: <ANALYSIS>
    <CELG_NAME>Build</CELG_NAME>
    <CELG_VALUE>0</CELG_VALUE>
</ANALYSIS>

CE_DEVLOG: <ANALYSIS>
    <CELG_NAME>RAM</CELG_NAME>
    <CELG_VALUE>135143424</CELG_VALUE>
</ANALYSIS>

CE_DEVLOG: <ANALYSIS>
    <CELG_NAME>FreeRAM</CELG_NAME>
    <CELG_VALUE>107048960</CELG_VALUE>
</ANALYSIS>

CE_DEVLOG: <ANALYSIS>
    <CELG_NAME>Store</CELG_NAME>
    <CELG_VALUE>83693568</CELG_VALUE>
</ANALYSIS>

CE_DEVLOG: <ANALYSIS>
    <CELG_NAME>FreeStore</CELG_NAME>
    <CELG_VALUE>54960128</CELG_VALUE>
</ANALYSIS>

APP:  scanner.exe

IP_ON_HEAP:  8042c0e0

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 8042c0e0 to 80428ca8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STACKIMMUNE

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_ZEROED_STACK

FRAME_ONE_INVALID: 1

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000 00000000 scanner.exe!Unknown+0x0


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  scanner.exe!Unknown

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: scanner

IMAGE_NAME:  scanner.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE_c0000005_scanner.exe!Unloaded

BUCKET_ID:  ARM_APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_ZEROED_STACK_scanner.exe!Unknown

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Here is unassembled instructions and loaded modules

```
1:000:armce> u 80428ca8
80428ca8 e5913010 ldr         r3,[r1,#0x10]
80428cac e3530001 cmp         r3,#1
80428cb0 0a000005 beq         80428ccc
80428cb4 e3530002 cmp         r3,#2
80428cb8 1a00000c bne         80428cf0
80428cbc e1a03004 mov         r3,r4
80428cc0 e2802010 add         r2,r0,#0x10
80428cc4 eb000830 bl          8042ad8c
1:000:armce> lm
start    end        module name
00010000 00074000   scanner   (deferred)             
40010000 400a6000   coredll    (deferred)             
400b0000 400c2000   fpcrt      (deferred)             
40120000 4012d000   zlib       (deferred)             
40140000 401a5000   commctrl   (deferred)             
40290000 402a0000   iphlpapi   (deferred)             
402b0000 402bd000   ws2        (deferred)             
402c0000 402c6000   wspm       (deferred)             
402d0000 402d6000   nspm       (deferred)             
402f0000 402fb000   ssllsp     (deferred)             
40380000 403ba000   netui      (deferred)             
40400000 40405000   lpcrt      (deferred)             
404b0000 404b7000   secur32    (deferred)             
405f0000 4066a000   ole32      (deferred)             
40670000 406a5000   oleaut32   (deferred)             
406d0000 40722000   rpcrt4     (deferred)             
40730000 4078b000   imaging    (deferred)             
419b0000 419c2000   mscoree    (deferred)             
41e30000 41e5b000   rsaenh     (deferred)             
41f30000 41f37000   rcm2api32   (deferred)             
41f40000 41f53000   edbgtl     (deferred)             
41f70000 41f7f000   tcpconnectiona   (deferred)             
41f80000 41fbd000   netcfagl2_0   (deferred)             
41fc0000 41fd0000   sqlceme30   (deferred)             
42010000 420db000   mscoree2_0   (deferred)             
42160000 42184000   sqlceer30en   (deferred)             
80400000 80420000   NK         (deferred)
```

And info from CE Watson Dump Viewer

[image: enter iDump Info]

[image: Processes]

[image: Modules]

[image: Callstack]

[image: Memory Block]

[image: Threads]

At this point I'm mostly looking for a direction.  If someone could say this problem is due to the app, due to a dependent library, or due to the device/OS, it would be a great starting point.

Comment: Too bad the images got shrunk, though I found that entering the URL for them directly looked fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cool! I love seeing crash dumps from architectures other than x86/x64 :)

I have zero experience with debugging CR ARM, however I can decipher a couple of things from here:

> GetContextState failed, 0x80070570

General these errors are bad and mean that the dump file is corrupted in some way.

Here's your faulting instruction:

> ldr         r3,[r1,#0x10]

And, according to your exception record, the crash happened because you tried to reference address 0x10:

> Attempt to read from address 00000010

Thus, r1 must be zero in the previous instruction. Typically when you see this pattern it's a dereference of a NULL pointer to a data structure, so 0x10 is the offset of the field of the data structure you're trying to access.

Unfortunately the stack is garbage from there (with some indication that it was zeroed somehow), so it's hard to get more detail from there. Do the following commands show any information?

```
u 80428ca8
lm
```

Comment: I've added the requested info...not really knowing what I'm looking at, the instructions are near the range of the kernel (NK)?  How can they be past the end of the range though?

Comment: @snoone: Where did you learn to read crash dumps? I'd like to learn this, too!

Comment: @tcarvin That seems strange. It looks to me like your loaded module list is incomplete and that the faulting instruction is in another module not listed. This is usually either a problem with your symbols or (again) a corrupted dump. Though I'm basing this off of x86/x64 dumps, so maybe there's something weird about CE dumps. Do you install software on these devices?

Comment: @jp2code Practice :) I've been doing exclusively kernel mode development for almost 12 years now, which means I've seen LOTS of crash dumps. I once wrote a long response here about where to start, see this question: http://bit.ly/KF2tLq. Feel free to contact me though if you have specific questions.

Comment: I agree with jp2code, pretty cool skill.  I think I can adjust via the registry whether this is a full dump or a mini dump, and I can direct it to place it on an SD card so there is room for it.  Personally, I mostly develop in .NET so I don't need to deal with dumps too often.

Comment: Looks like it is a "Context Dump", see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee480413(v=winembedded.60).aspx

Comment: @tcarvin That makes sense. It's similar to a, "triage" or, "mini" dump on Big Windows. Not always very useful for tracking down problems, one of the larger dump types is usually better.

Comment: @snoone In your opinion, is this error something I need to take up with the device OEM (ie a problem with the kernel or some other low-level system)?  As some additionalinformation, this app worked before the OEM released a new OS build in December.

Comment: @snoone Added more content, if that helps at all

Comment: The Big Windows model is that a bug in your application should only crash your application, not the entire O/S. So, unless that's different than the CE model it's automatically not your application's fault. It's hard to know exactly though without more details on the environment and what exactly your application is doing.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I'll mark the answer as accepted as you've provided great info given the amount of data I was able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

Landing in the middle of the kernel is the worst, because it can be very hard to work out where you are and how you got there. Unfortunately it is very hard to get hold of debugging symbols, as they are unique to each platform - you would have to get them from Motorola, not from Microsoft.

The convention on the ARM processor is for the return address of the current leaf function to be stored in the Link Register, `lr`. Each function's prolog is responsible for storing this register's value in a location that won't be trashed by any functions that it calls. In order to be able to unwind the stack, if a hardware exception occurs, Windows CE requires that the prolog takes particular forms. The virtual unwinder algorithm is described at [ARM Prolog and Epilog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881423.aspx) ('virtual' because Windows exception handling doesn't *actually* unwind the stack until it has discovered the actual handler for the exception, but it can only *find* that handler by walking the stack). You can follow that algorithm to walk back through the stack yourself.

The [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881424.aspx) at that link are actually quite atypical - code only saves r0-r3 on the stack before saving any persistent registers for a C/C++ varargs function. This is so that they are next to any additional arguments. The Windows CE ARM calling convention passes the first four arguments to the function in registers r0-r3, then the fifth and subsequent arguments on the stack. A function that uses `va_args` therefore has to push the first four onto the stack next to the others, so it can treat all arguments the same.

Normally, an ARM function will start with a `stmdb` (STore Multiple, Decrement Before) instruction that stores all the volatile registers overwritten by the function. This instruction isn't used very often in normal code, so the `stmdb` is nearly always the first instruction of the function. You can therefore work out from that instruction, and from the stack, what the value of `lr` was and therefore where to return to. You can then repeat that for each method until you get somewhere recognizable. Hopefully this will be in an import section of a DLL, but it's probable that it will be in mscoree2_0.dll or netcfagl2_0.dll. You will probably need to search a disassembly of the Compact Framework assemblies to find what managed code called into that native entry point.